# SSRS Report generating #Error without details

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, group-by, sum, iif

This is a sub section of my tablix.

[image]

These are invisible columns that I will pull out into text boxes so that I can reference elsewhere. The data I have to reference has to be in the main group row or else i get en error message.

This is the code in column A

```
=Sum(iif(Parameters!season.Value = Fields!season.Value, Fields!pkg_due_amt.Value, 0))
```

This is the code in column B and it generates an error.

```
=Sum(iif(Fields!inDateRange.Value = TRUE and Parameters!season.Value = Fields!season.Value, Fields!pkg_due_amt.Value, 0))
```

If I adjust  in column B I had this code:

```
=Sum(iif(Fields!inDateRange.Value = TRUE and Parameters!season.Value = Fields!season.Value, 1, 0))
```

The only difference between the two lines above is that I am trying to sum up a field `pkg_due_amt` rather then 1. The 1 in the true field doesn't generate an error the `pkg_due_amt` does.

This is the first issue. As you can see to the right of the 701947. is an #Error.

[image: repor]

The second issue is that it appears like this when generated/previewed. If you look at the above image the first/general header row is also generating an #Error. That is the top highest most grouping. When I tried replacing the `pkg_due_amt` with a 1 it once again worked but this is not helpful. What I need is a summation of the field.

Compilation Errors read as follows:

[image]

```
Warning 1   [rsAggregateOfMixedDataTypes] The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox794.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ uses an aggregate function on data of varying data types.  Aggregate functions other than First, Last, Previous, Count, and CountDistinct can only aggregate data of a single data type.  ... 0   0   

Warning 2   [rsAggregateOfMixedDataTypes] The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox814.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ uses an aggregate function on data of varying data types.  Aggregate functions other than First, Last, Previous, Count, and CountDistinct can only aggregate data of a single data type.  ... 0   0   

Warning 3   [rsAggregateOfMixedDataTypes] The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox789.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ uses an aggregate function on data of varying data types.  Aggregate functions other than First, Last, Previous, Count, and CountDistinct can only aggregate data of a single data type.  ... 0   0
```

Comment: @DaleBurrell where do I look? I see a list of warnings that all basically state a given object is "Transparent" but I see no error messages.

Comment: @DaleBurrell Thank you. It was under output as compilation errors. I read them I'm still not sure how to fix them. We basically just want everything added if it meets that criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that `pkg_due_amt` is not the same data-type as `0` probably as simple as one is an `int` and one is a `decimal` - you solve it by using the cast functions e.g. `CDec(Fields!pkg_due_amt.Value), CDec(0)`